# Can't find out why cudaMemcpy fails using curand library functions

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to initialize in a random manner the weights ( stored as floats ) of a neural network using CURAND functions.

I first initialize the neural netwotk with some values and after that I attempt to copy the two matrices in the nn struct ( nn stands for neural network ), that should store the weight values ( nn.wih, and nn.who ) into the Device memory.

Then I call a function that should randomize the matrices' values (assignRandomWeight), which launches two kernels that holds curand functions.

Finally I try to copy the resulting matrices back to the host memory through a cudaMemcpy call, but at this point I get the error "an illegal memory access was encountered".

I tried to print the values of the Device copy matrices of wih and who, which are d_wih and d_who. They seems to be correct; I left in the code two functions usefull for debugging :

checkCudaError can be called to check the last cudaError_t string message

showValues is useful to print the values of a Device allcated arraay

I extracted a sample of my code that compile and presents the same error, plese help me out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include<cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

struct TNeuralNetwork {
    int input_neurons;
    int hidden_neurons;
    int output_neurons;
    float *wih; //first layer of weights (from input layer to hidden layer)
    float *who; //second layer of weights (from hidden layer to output layer)
    float *wih_old; //for the momentum
    float *who_old; //for the momentum
    float *erro;
    float *errh;
    float l; //learning rate
    float m; //momentum
    float *i; //values into input neurons
    float *h; //values into hidden neurons
    float *o; //values into output neurons
};

__host__ void checkCudaError(char *str);
__global__ void showValues(float *d_v, int dim);
__global__ void init_rand(unsigned int seed, curandState_t state_wih);
__global__ void generateRandomValues(curandState_t state_wih, float *wih, float *who, int inp, int hid, int out);
void assignRandomWeight(struct TNeuralNetwork *nn, float *d_wih, float *d_who);
void initNeuralNetwork(struct TNeuralNetwork *nn, int bands, int nlabel);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct TNeuralNetwork nn;

    //Declare Device variables
    float *d_wih;
    float *d_who;

    unsigned int v;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    initNeuralNetwork(&nn, 102, 10);

    //Allocate Device Memory
    v = (nn.input_neurons + 1)*(nn.hidden_neurons);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_wih, (nn.input_neurons + 1)*(nn.hidden_neurons)*sizeof(float));
    checkCudaError("malloc1");

    //cudaMalloc((void**)&d_who, (nn.hidden_neurons + 1)*nn.output_neurons * sizeof(float));
    //checkCudaError("malloc2");

    for (int i = 0; i < (nn.input_neurons + 1); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nn.hidden_neurons; j++){
            nn.wih[i*nn.hidden_neurons + j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (nn.hidden_neurons + 1); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nn.output_neurons; j++){
            nn.who[i*nn.output_neurons + j] = 0;
        }
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_wih, nn.wih, (nn.input_neurons + 1)*(nn.hidden_neurons)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    checkCudaError("memcpy0");
    //showValues << <v, 1 >> >(d_wih, v); TEST

    //cudaMemcpy(d_who, nn.who, (nn.hidden_neurons + 1)*nn.output_neurons*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //checkCudaError("memcpy0.1");

    assignRandomWeight(&nn, d_wih, d_who);

    cudaMemcpy(nn.wih, d_wih, (nn.input_neurons + 1)*(nn.hidden_neurons)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //showValues << <v, 1 >> >(d_wih, v); TEST
    checkCudaError("memcpy1");

    //cudaMemcpy(nn.who, d_who, (nn.hidden_neurons + 1)*nn.output_neurons*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //checkCudaError("memcpy2");

    //printf("WIH:\n");
    //for (int i = 0; i < (nn.input_neurons + 1); i++){
    //  for (int j = 0; j < (nn.hidden_neurons); j++){
    //      printf("%.12f\t", nn.wih[i*(nn.hidden_neurons) + j]);
    //  }
    //  printf("\n\n");
    //}
    //printf("WHO:\n");
    //for (int i = 0; i < (nn.hidden_neurons + 1); i++){
    //  for (int j = 0; j < nn.output_neurons; j++){
    //      printf("%.12f\t", nn.wih[i*nn.output_neurons + j]);
    //  }
    //  printf("\n\n");
    //}

    cudaFree(d_wih);
    cudaFree(d_who);

    return 0;
}

__host__ void checkCudaError(char *str){
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess){
        printf("Cuda Error at %s: %s \n", str, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

__global__ void showValues(float *d_v, int dim){
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < dim){
        printf("elemento[%d] = %.4f\n", tid, d_v[tid]);
    }
}

__global__ void init_rand(unsigned int seed, curandState_t state_wih){

    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    curand_init(seed, 0, tid, &state_wih);
}

__global__ void generateRandomValues(curandState_t state_wih, float *wih, float *who, int inp, int hid, int out){

    int tid = (blockIdx.x)*(blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

    printf("%.7f", (float)curand(&state_wih + tid));
    if (tid <= (inp + 1)*hid){
        wih[tid] = (float)curand_uniform(&state_wih + tid);

        printf("%.7f", wih[tid]);
    }
    if (tid <= (hid + 1)*out){
        who[tid] = (float)curand_uniform(&state_wih + tid);
        printf("%.7f", who[tid]);
    }
}

void initNeuralNetwork(struct TNeuralNetwork *nn, int bands, int nlabel) {

    nn->input_neurons = bands;
    nn->output_neurons = nlabel;
    //nn->hidden_neurons = (int)((bands + nlabel)/2.0f);
    nn->hidden_neurons = (int)((bands + nlabel)*2.0f / 3.0f);
    nn->l = 0.001;
    nn->m = 0.2;
    nn->wih = (float*)malloc((bands + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons) * sizeof(float)); //+1 for the bias
    nn->who = (float*)malloc((nn->hidden_neurons + 1)*nlabel * sizeof(float));//+1 for the bias
    nn->wih_old = (float*)malloc((bands + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons) * sizeof(float)); //+1 for the bias
    nn->who_old = (float*)malloc((nn->hidden_neurons + 1)*nlabel * sizeof(float));//+1 for the bias
    nn->i = (float*)malloc(bands * sizeof(float));
    nn->h = (float*)malloc(nn->hidden_neurons * sizeof(float));
    nn->o = (float*)malloc(nlabel * sizeof(float));
    nn->errh = (float*)malloc(nn->hidden_neurons * sizeof(float));
    nn->erro = (float*)malloc(nlabel * sizeof(float));
    memset(nn->wih_old, 0, (bands + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons) * sizeof(float));
    memset(nn->who_old, 0, (nn->hidden_neurons + 1)*nlabel * sizeof(float));


}

//curand
void assignRandomWeight(struct TNeuralNetwork *nn, float *d_wih, float *d_who) {

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    curandState_t state_wih;

    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int seed = rand();

    //Alloco la matrice di curandState_t per la randomizzaione, in uscita dalla funzione non mi servirà più
    cudaMalloc((void**)&state_wih, (nn->input_neurons + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons)* sizeof(curandState_t));

    dim3 gridSize(ceil((double)((nn->input_neurons + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons)) / 32));
    dim3 blockSize(32);

    init_rand << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(seed, state_wih);

    generateRandomValues << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(state_wih, d_wih, d_who, nn->input_neurons, nn->hidden_neurons, nn->output_neurons);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Incorrect Indexing" will produce out-of-bounds memory access within the kernel. The CUDA runtime will destroy your context at the point where the error occurred within the kernel, after which *no CUDA operations which rely the the context* can be performed. The `cudaMemcpy`call fails because your context has been destroyed. There is no way to avoid this.

NVIDIA supply a utility called [cuda-memcheck](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-memcheck) with the CUDA toolkit. Use that instead to diagnose what is going wrong with your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'v found my error:

I was making a bad use of the "curandState_t" type variable in the assignRandomWight function, I had to use a pointer.

this is the correct version:

```
void assignRandomWeight(struct TNeuralNetwork *nn, float *d_wih, float *d_who) {

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    curandState_t *state_wih;

    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int seed = rand();

    //Alloco la matrice di curandState_t per la randomizzaione, in uscita dalla funzione non mi servirà più
    cudaMalloc((void**)&state_wih, (nn->input_neurons + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons)* sizeof(curandState_t));

    dim3 gridSize(ceil((double)((nn->input_neurons + 1)*(nn->hidden_neurons)) / 32));
    dim3 blockSize(32);

    init_rand << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(seed, state_wih);

    generateRandomValues << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(state_wih, d_wih, d_who, nn->input_neurons, nn->hidden_neurons, nn->output_neurons);

}
```

and the correct version for the two kernels:

```
__global__ void generateRandomValues( curandState_t *state_wih, float *wih, float *who, int inp, int hid, int out){

    int tid = (blockIdx.x)*(blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid<=(inp+1)*hid ){
        printf("\ncasual : %f", (float)curand_uniform(&state_wih[tid]));
        wih[tid] = (float)curand_uniform(&state_wih[tid]);
    }
    if (tid<=(hid+1)*out){
        who[tid] = (float)curand_uniform(&state_wih[tid]);
    }
}

__global__ void init_rand(unsigned int seed, curandState_t *state_wih){

    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    curand_init(seed, tid, 0, &state_wih[tid]);
}
```